# WIX code Velo, delay on showing text when clock radio button

Tags: velo

I'm trying to create a "quiz" that will show an answer (retrieved from a database) depending on which radio button one selects.

I'll do multiple per page, but so far only setting up one question to make sure it works before I continue to make the others.

ISSUE:

It seems that the answer DOESN'T show when 1st clicked, but it shows if you click another radio button, or double click, the radio button.

Any help? I could use some fresh eyes. Thanks

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

let answer;

$w.onReady(function () {
});

// retrieve answer from 'Quiz' databse
export function getAnswer(rdoSetValue) {
    wixData.query("Quiz")
        .eq("value", rdoSetValue)
        .find()
        .then((results) => {
            if (wixData.query("Quiz").eq("value", rdoSetValue)) {
                let items = results.items;
                let item = items[0];
                answer = item.answerText;
                return answer;
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            let errorMsg = error.message;
            let code = error.code;
            console.log(errorMsg + " + code= " + code);
        });
}

// Expand and show answer text
export function displayAnswers(radioButtonSet) {
    const rdoSet = radioButtonSet;
    let rdoSetValue = $w('#rdbQ1').value;
    getAnswer(rdoSetValue);
    if ($w('#rdbQ1').value === rdoSetValue) {
        $w('#boxA1').expand()
        $w('#txtA1').html = answer;
    } else {
        $w('#boxA1').collapse()
    }
}

// onClick question 1
export function rdbQ1_click(event) {
    displayAnswers($w('#rdbQ1'));
}
```